# Filtering data to only keep up to 10 duplicates in two variables, with missing data

Tags: r

We have survey data for a survey that respondents can take multiple times, and we want to retain only the first 10 entries per respondent.  The respondent must provide either an email address or a phone number, which we want to use to check for duplicates.

Using R, I ordered the data by response date, and used the following code to add counts for the email addresses and phone numbers:

```
surveydata <- surveydata %>%
  group_by(email) %>%
  mutate(email_count = row_number())
surveydata <- surveydata %>%
  group_by(phone) %>%
  mutate(phone_count = row_number())
```

I thought that I could just filter out the entries where email_count or phone_count was over 10.  However this process also counted all of the NAs together, so if I filtered out all of the entries with counts over 10, I'd be deleting a lot of entries that we actually want to keep.

I tried the following if statement to try to reset the email_count and phone_count if the email or phone entries were blank, but it didn't work:

```
# This doesn't work
if (is.na(surveydata$email)) {
surveydata$email_count = 0
}
```

Even though the code ran without error, none of the entries without emails had email_count set to 0.

I used the following code to create new data tables that list the emails and phone numbers that occur more than 10 times:

```
dup_emails <- data.frame(table(surveydata$email))
dup_phones <- data.frame(table(surveydata$phone))
dup_emails <- dup_emails[dup_emails$Freq > 10,]
dup_phones <- dup_phones[dup_phones$Freq > 10,]
```

I would like to create a For loop to check each row in surveydata where, if the email address or phone number match one of the email addresses or phone numbers in dup_emails or dup_phones, and the email_count or phone_count is over 10, then set a new variable "remove" to 1.  After that, I could then filter out any data where "remove" = 1.

I wrote the following code, but it's not working.  All of the values for "remove" remain 0:

```
# This doesn't work
surveydata$remove <- 0
for (i in length(unique(dup_emails$Var1))) {
  if(surveydata$email == dup_emails[i,1] && thdsweeps$email_count > 10) {
    surveydata$remove <- 1
  }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] of your data, or something approximating your data?

Comment: Can you use the `dput` function to paste to minimal example of your data into your question? Most people will be understandably hesitant to download a random file from a link given to them by stranger on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

I created a new TRUE/FALSE variable for whether or not the email or phone variables were NAs.

```
surveydata$email_remove <- is.na(surveydata$email)
surveydata$phone_remove <- is.na(surveydata$phone)
```

And then filtered out all rows where the email or phone counts were above 10 and the "remove" variables were FALSE.

```
surveydata_clean <- surveydata[!(surveydata$email_count > 10 & surveydata$email_remove == FALSE),]
surveydata_clean <- surveydata_clean[!(surveydata_clean$phone_count > 10 & surveydata_clean$phone_remove == FALSE),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
surveydata <- surveydata %>%
 group_by(phone) %>%
 mutate(phone_count = row_number()) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 group_by(email) %>%
 mutate(email_count = row_number()) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 #keep the records that have missing values for emails and phone numbers
 filter(is.na(email)&is.na(phone))
```

Comment: Thanks, but we need to keep the records that have missing values for emails and phone numbers. That's the trouble that I'm having...

Comment: Try the revised answer?